Delete query returning "could not extract resultset"
I have this delete method in my spring boot repository class and for some reason it keeps throwing the "could not extract ResultSet" error when it is obviously a void method.
The problem here is, I have similar methods in other classes that are not throwing this error.
PS: I'm using postgresql.
How can I resolve this?
See method below:
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from v2_team_menu_item_mapping where team_id = ?1 ")
    void removeAllMenuItemsAssignedToTeam(Long teamId);

See errors thrown:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)


what is this -> where team_id = ?1     ??

@Stultuske that's how you pass ordered parameters to PostgreSQL prepared statements. See here

@FedericoklezCulloca thanks. Our projects tend to use ItemPreparedStatementSetters for this, different syntax altogether it would seem
